# List just the filenames (not directory structure) of files with a certain permission only in sub directories

Tags: files, permissions, find

I want to know how to list only the name of the sub directory that has a certain permission.

The command I got so far is this:

```
find */* -maxdepth 2 -perm 770
```

but this just gives me this:

```
file1/file2
```

That file2 is that one with the permission 770; I just want to print out "file2"

Comment: You're specifying `-maxdepth 2`, if you only want to print that file, you must find inside `file1`. Remember `find` is recursive and it will show you the location of the files you're looking for. `$ find /file1/ -maxdepth 2 -perm 770` unless you use some extra command

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would be generally useful to know only the basename of the result of `find`.  How would you know which directory it's in?  (And why on earth do you have a directory named `file1`?)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.  Here are two:

1. use `basename` with `find`:

   `find . -type f -perm 770 -exec basename {} \;`
2. use `sed` to strip off the path:

   `find . -type f -perm 770 | sed -e 's:^.*/::'`